# Preventing missed scheduled posts on WordPress 3.3.1

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, cron

I am using a modified version of WordPress 3.3.1 and have been alerted to the fact that scheduled posts have been "missed" and are not posting automatically on time, meaning they have to be manually posted.

In the Posts admin in WP, the post shows as "Missed Schedule". This happens for all scheduled posts, AFAIK.

I came across [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/scheduled-posts-not-launching?replies=16) on the WP forum and talks about the [WP_Cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) function, however what it doesn't state is - do I need to do anything to get the scheduled task to fire?

Traditionally, I would think of adding a script to the crontab - however I am led to believe that `WP_Cron` is a "lazy cron" and is fired via a PHP script and not through a Unix Crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this to `wp-config.php` and it appears to work on a test environment (haven't tested in a LIVE environment though)

```
define( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes WP_Cron only runs when someone accesses a page, it's not exactly the same as a Unix Crontab.  I believe it was created as a workaround for servers that didn't have crontab.

More info here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/insights-into-wp-cron-an-introduction-to-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress/